# htaccess match specific file types in root directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I would like to match specific file types within the root directory the website. This htaccess file also sits in the root directly.

I've got this so far:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|png|ico)$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

None of my attempts to restrict the matches to the same directory have been successful. I'm sure it's something super simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way:

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.(php|png|ico)$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that  only looks at the file name. It does not look at the directory part of the filename at all.

There is a  but your not able to use it in a htacces file.

So the only way is through a Rewrite Rule. Something like this:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule "^(subdir/).*/.*\.(html|json)$" "-" [PT,L]
        # -- Deny Everything Not Matched Above -- #
        RewriteRule "/*" "-" [F]
    </IfModlue>
```

The above will only allow html or json files to be accessed in a second (or greater) sub-directory within a directory called subdir in the same folder as the htaccess file. Everything else will be forbidden. Assuming mod_rewrite is installed. The files will also be treated as files, which is not the default behavior for a rewrite rule.